# Pandoc convert md with image to pdf

Tags: pdf, terminal, markdown, pandoc, file-conversion

My md file contains a list of images like:

> "! [image-9H7092HQ.jpg] (Beginners_Russian_with_Interactive_Online_Workbook/image-9H7092HQ.jpg)"

> "! [image-EVZX3ID8.jpg] (Beginners_Russian_with_Interactive_Online_Workbook/image-EVZX3ID8.jpg)"

(There is no space between "!" and "[", and "]" and "(")
The images are in the another file that is in the same file as md file.

I ran

`pandoc -f markdown -t pdf Beginners_Russian_with_Interactive_Online_Workbook.md`

on terminal, but it gives me error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.378 \centering
```

Then I ran

```
H <return>
```

it returns
`` zsh: parse error near `\n' ``

I am not sure what went wrong. And how I can turn this md file with images to pdf. I will be very appreciated if anyone can help me. Thanks.

---

The main problem is fixed, but there is a dimension problem with the output file(see below)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely issue is that pandoc converts images without surrounding text into figures. Try

```
pandoc -f markdown-implicit_figures -t latex -o OUTFILE.pdf YOUR-FILE.md
```

That should disable this feature and solve the issue.

Comment: I tried that, but terminal returns a very long list of characters: mostly "?" mixed with some characters I don't know and some letters. This is part of it:}?L?q%????d2?? 2
???Z?ȸ&??QyYl????ĸr?=W?????/ɔW~??W????B?¸???R?EV???.SM֑5h??R??{?k?H?ٍk???[??M?l???e?WU??r.~zs?L?q?,?F??l??a2m?U?Եʝ?<?!?a\??nS^H?G?32
                                                  ?

Comment: Looks like the result was printed to the terminal instead of written to a file. Use `-o OUTFILE.pdf` to avoid this. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that fixed the problem; thank you so much! But there is a dimension problem with the image in the output file(see above screenshot), is there any way to fix this?